# How to take input after string variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct book {
  int bookid;
  string bookname;
  float prize;
};
     

int main(){
        book b1;
        cout<<"Enter bookid"<<" "<<"Enter bookname"<<" "<<"enter prize"<<endl;
        cin>>b1.bookid;
        getline(cin,b1.bookname);
        cin>>b1.prize;
        cout<<b1.bookid<< " "<<b1.bookname<<" "<<b1.prize<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

But after taking book name, it skips taking prize and direct show output.

Comment: The reason is that different styles of input on the same stream (e.g. `cin >> b1bookid` `getline(cin,b1.bookname)`) handle whitespace differently, therefore give strange interactions depending on what the user enters.  The *reliable* solution is to interact with the stream using one style (e.g. read everything from `cin` using `getline()` and then check/parse the input).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) (Depending on how you enter the input this issue will come up)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `cin.ignore()` after `cin>> b1.bookid;` to flush the newline character out of the buffer in between as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct book {
  int bookid;
  std::string bookname;
  float prize;
};
     

int main(){
        book b1;
        std::cout<<"Enter bookid"<<" ";
        std::cin>>b1.bookid;
        
        std::cin.ignore(); //ADDED THIS 
        
        std::cout<<"Enter bookname";
        std::getline(std::cin,b1.bookname);
        
        std::cout<<"enter prize"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>b1.prize;
        std::cout<<b1.bookid<< " "<<b1.bookname<<" "<<b1.prize<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/mY664_Dzf).

Comment: This solution will not work, if you enter additional spaces after the number and before pressing enter. Either read all characters until newline (with the `ignore` function, see example in CPP reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), or use the idiomatic correct approach `std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, b1.bookname);`. Additionally. Maybe you could consider to stop your usual pattern to just drop code,  and give some explanations.  Maybe you can delete your answer or at least update it . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I have mentioned at the end of my edited answer that not to mix `getline` and `cin`.  For OP's original question my answer/explanation is  enough.